# ScrollView scroll automaticallly when it is full

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView. There is a 'Add' button in the ScrollView. When clicking the button, a new EditText is created on top of the button. When clicking several tiems, the scrollView is full of EditText and the button is out of bounds. My question is how i can make the ScrollView automatically scroll when the buttton is going to be out of bounds. And make my button staying at the bottom of ScrollView. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make the scroll view to scroll down each time you click the button, try placing the below code in button click listener.

```
ScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
```